# How to by pass \ in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

```
<proxybypass var="proxybypass">xxx.yyy.com|\DDD.yyy.com</proxybypass>
```

Where DDD is server name as defined `${sname}`

unable to pass the variable \ after `xxx.yyy.com|` when using below code:

in short I have to by pass |\ character in updateflag

```
updateflag="<proxybypass var=\"proxybypass\">xxx.yyy.com|\"${sname}".yyy.com</proxybypass>"

sed -i ''"$line_number"'a '"$updateflag"'' $xmlval
```

Comment: Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible change the updateflag, so that it contains an additional backslash (to escape the one you want to keep):

```
updateflag="...|\\\\${name}..."
```

Then:

```
sed "1a $updateflag" <<< "test"
```

Gives:

```
test
|\DDD
```

Comment: excellent .. It worked . thanks a lot for your quick help . I was not not expecting so many times backslash solve the problem .. thanks a lot